# How to pass the username into multi pages in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loopback

I'm totally new to reactjs. I have successfully created user register tab and login tab also. 
problem is after login; the username should be show into the `nav` bar. 
As my site I have created nav bar page(NavBar.js) and login page (Login.js) separately 
As my learn `sessionStorage` and `props` can possible for this. but I'm totally confused how to use it. please anyone give hint to solve my problem. my backend is loopback
This is my `login.js`

```
const FormItem = Form.Item;

    export default class Login extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email: "",
          password: "",
          details: ""
        };
      }

      handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
      };

      onSubmit(e) {
        var email = this.state.email;
        var password = this.state.password;
        axios
          .get(
            `http://localhost:3000/api/UserLogins/findOne?filter={"where":{"email":"${email}"}}`
          )
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ details: response.data }, () => {
              if (password === this.state.details.password) {
                console.log("login");
              } else {
                console.log("not login");
              }
            });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      render() {
        let UserLoginDetail = this.state.details.username;
        sessionStorage.setItem(UserLoginDetail, this.state.details.username);

        return (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <FormItem>
                <Input
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  prefix={<Icon type="mail" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="abcd@gmail.com"
                />
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem>
                <Input
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </FormItem>
              <FormItem>
                <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">
                  Forgot password
                </a>
                <Button
                  type="primary"
                  htmlType="submit"
                  className="login-form-button"
                >
                  Log in
                </Button>
              </FormItem>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

NavBar.js code is

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Collapse,Navbar,NavbarToggler,NavbarBrand,Nav,NavItem,NavLink} from 'reactstrap';
import ResizeImage from 'react-resize-image';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';
import { Tabs,Icon } from 'antd';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  state = { visible: false }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  }

  handleOk = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  }

  handleCancel = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    let myItem = sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
    return (
      <Row className="vert-align">
      <Col push={24}>
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" white="true" expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">
          <ResizeImage
            src={require('../image/logo.png')}
            alt="logo"

          />
      </NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/">Home</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/Car">All Cars</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/Rate">Rates</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/About">About Us</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/BecomePartner"><Icon type="team" />  Become a Partner</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <p>{myItem}</p>
              <div>
                <Button type="default" onClick={this.showModal}>
                  <Icon type="login" />Login
                </Button>

                <Modal
                  visible={this.state.visible}
                  onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                  onOk={this.handleOk}
                >
                  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
                    <TabPane tab="Login" key="1"><Login/>
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Register" key="2"><Register/></TabPane>
                  </Tabs>
                </Modal>

              </div>

            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar> 
      </div>
      </Col >
      </Row >
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox demo with your code? In your case if it is small application you can manage sending props from parent to child. If you think your application is large then use redux state management library

Comment: @HemadriDasari sir I have updeted my login.js ..I tried to create codesandbox but, I couldn't sir.. sorry My application is large. so as you have mentioned how can I use  redux state management library

Comment: It’s not so easy to explain how to integrate redux into an application in comments here. You can check online tutorials about how to integrate redux into react application. https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-redux-in-your-reactjs-app-in-just-10-mi

Comment: @HemadriDasari thanks sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In  Login File use SessionStorage in this way:-

`sessionStorage.setItem('UserName', this.state.details.username);`

In current code you are using key as this.state.details.username and value as this.state.details.username.

**Key Should always be fixed,it should not be dependent upon user input,so that you can use it to fetch the value.**

**After NavBar Code Shared :-**

This code should be placed inside

```
 axios
 .get(
  `http://localhost:3000/api/UserLogins/findOne?filter={"where":{"email":"${email}"}}`
          )
     .then(response => {
      this.setState({ details: response.data }, () => {
       if (password === this.state.details.password) {
        console.log("login");
        sessionStorage.setItem('UserName', this.state.details.username);
        this.props.handeLogin(); 
        /*It will change state of NavBar 
         Component,and it would be re-rendered.
         So,we will get new User Name from 
         session.*/

       } else {
          console.log("not login");
          }
        });
          })
```

Session Value should be set inside this axios call is because here the value is changing,
It should not be assigned  in render method,because render method would be called each time state changes.

In Nav File fetch user name :-
`sessionStorage.getItem('userName');`

In Navfile add state property isLoggedIn,

```
 this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      isLoggedIn:false
    };
```

Then add method handlelogin() :-

```
handleLogin=()=>{
   this.setState({
      isLoggedIn:true
    })
}.
```

We followed the process of changing state, because Nav Component would not re-render even the SessionStorage userName changes.

In case, userName is required in another components it could be fetched using :-
`sessionStorage.getItem('userName');`

If You Plan to use `Redux` for State Management visit :- https://redux.js.org/.

Redux is based upon `Single Source of Truth`.It's like a component for example, Login would update redux store with new userName and the NavBar component will get the updated userName as it would have subscribed to store.

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Comment: hank you sir. but, sessionStorage.getItem('userName'); not getting username which is loggedin

Comment: Can you share NavBar code, I hope you are rendering NavBar component after Login.

Comment: Are you getting console.log('login') ?

Comment: yes sir i got console.log('login') . I have updated my NavBar.js sir

Comment: I have updated the answer after refering to NavBar code

Comment: sir after updated as you are mention, I got TypeError: _this2.props.handleLogin is not a function on Login.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186639/discussion-between-arebhy-sri-and-sahil-arora).

Comment: sir, Could you please help me to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235218/how-to-add-multiple-images-by-using-formdata-in-reactjs

Comment: Sorry,I have not worked with form-data and uploading.