# How to add multiple images by using formData in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, form-data

Im new to Reactjs. I am using loopback-storage-connecter to store images/files. now my problem is to upload more than one file by using `formData()`

my code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        car_photo : [],
        Car_Image : []
    }
}
fileUploadCarImg = ()=> {
        const fd = new FormData();
        this.state.Car_Image.forEach((item , i) => {
            fd.append('image2',this.state.Car_Image, this.state.Car_Image.name )
        });

        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/attachmentBanks/Car_Image/upload',fd , {
            onUploadProgress : ProgressEvent => {
                console.log('Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total *100) + '%')
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                car_photo: res.data.result.files.image2[0].name,

            });

        });
    }

    fileSelectedCarImg = event =>{
        console.log(Array.from(event.target))
        this.setState({
            Car_Image: Array.from(event.target.files[0])
        })

    }
```

my input field is

```
<FormGroup>
<span>Car Image</span> 
  <input style={{display :'none'}} type="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedCarImg} ref={fileInput3 => this.fileInput3 = fileInput3 } required multiple />
 <Button onClick={()=>this.fileInput3.click()} ><Icon type="upload" />Choose Image
 </Button> &nbsp;
 <Button onClick={this.fileUploadCarImg}> upload </Button>
</FormGroup>
```

while using this code `Upload Progress: 100%` printed in console, but file didn't sore into the folder.
Please anyone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the working code

```
fileSelectedCarImg = event =>{
        const file = Array.from(event.target.files);
    this.setState({ file })
}

fileUploadCarImg =()=>{
        for (let index = 0; index < this.state.file.length; index++) {
            const element = this.state.file[index];
            const fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('image2',element,element.name )
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/attachmentBanks/Car_Image/upload',fd , {
                onUploadProgress : ProgressEvent => {
                    console.log('Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total *100) + '%')
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    car_photo: res.data.result.files.image2[0].name,
                });

            });

        }
    }
```